# How to draw borders around slides in latex beamer handouts

Tags: latex, frame, slide, beamer

I am using the LaTeX beamer package. How do I draw a border around each slide when I use the handout format (eg. {4 on 1}). I would like to have something silmilar to the "-d" option available in Unix "psnup" which I used with my old seminar style slides and PostScript output.

Comment: if you are printing from Adobe Reader, and I suppose, depending on your printer, you can print multiple pages per sheet and have Reader print the border around it. Its in Adobe Reader print dialog > Printer Properties > Finishing > Pages per sheet & the print page borders option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This adds a rectangle around each logical page:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, landscape, border shrink=5mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
```

Comment: @rcs and @ Tsf: This is great; but there is a problem; is say you are printing two frames in one page and number of frames is odd, then it creates an empty box at the very last page. Is there anyway to avoid it?